# Nvidia 319.17 - 640 x 480 screen and no unity post reboot

Tags: nvidia, 13.04, nvidia-optimus

Just asking, I am running 13.04 64bit on a Lenovo T430 with Nvidia Optimus capable card.

I tried the following instructions to enable the driver

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings 

cd /tmp

wget http://it.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/319.17/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-319.17.run

chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-319.17.run

sudo apt-get --purge remove xserver-xorg-video-nouveau

sudo service lightdm stop

cd /tmp

sudo sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-319.17.run
```

Confirm answering yes / OK to all the questions and at the end type:

```
sudo reboot -h
```

After the reboot and logging in the X window was I guess a small 640x480 screen and no Unity was loaded. I.e just the desktop,

I've since reinstalled...was just a basic install. But was there anything I did wrong or should do additionally or differently to get it to work.

Thanks

Comment: wondering why you installed both free and proprietary drivers ?
(nvidia-current + .run script from nvidia website)

Comment: Good question, actually have no idea, I just followed the instructions on [link]http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDQQ7gEwAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftranslate.google.co.uk%2Ftranslate%3Fhl%3Den%26sl%3Dit%26u%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.chimerarevo.com%2Fdriver-nvidia-319-17-linux%2F%26prev%3D%2Fsearch%253Fq%253DUbuntu%252B13.04%252B319.17%2526hl%253Den%2526biw%253D1600%2526bih%253D829&ei=Jb6DUc2VJIKS0QXh2oGQCw&usg=AFQjCNFHfyu9cTq8M5Pm9GausI1zL8ZjAQ[/link]

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue. This driver is not compatible with Ubuntu 13.04 and linux kernel 3.8. I removed the Nvidia driver by using  the command `sudo nvdia-uninstall`

Then restart the system. If you have optimus graphics, install bumblebee or else install the nvidia-310 driver for a dedicated Nvidia graphics card.

Restart the system and then move the .config file

`mv .config .config-bk`

Log out and log back in. This will bring back the Unity WM.

Comment: Thanks! Quick question what is the best way to install bumblebee, I also tried that at one point, and had no issues except the laptop refused to recognise the display port. The whole reason I was trying different drivers is I mainly use and external monitor and the standard nouveau driver performance is pretty sketchy. just noticed the post below has the wiki link.

Comment: I have connected to my TV after installing Bumblebee, it worked for me. I would say it works fine.  Install bumblebee ppa using the following command `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable`

Answer (score 0):

Installing multiple drivers simultaneously is a sure-shot way of messing the system. I strongly suggest purging, removing and cleaning all versions of the drivers installed.

run the .run file and go through the uninstallation process.
run `sudo apt-get purge -remove nvidia*` to be sure
check the loaded modules using
`lsmod | grep nvidia*` and
`lsmod | grep nouveau`

Once done with all, please follow the bumblebee installation instructions and it should work like a charm:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Installation

Comment: Thanks Charlie. have you had any issue with display port post bumblebee installation?

Comment: I've had many issueswhen I fiddled with a lot of options, but i dont think I had any issues with bumblebee...I may have got some issue once maybe, but dont recall now.